# Strcmp using assembly mips

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I have problems with my code, I developed it for when a string was equal it returned 0 and when it is different it returns 1. I Tested my code with this strings firstly `bruno` and `bruna` and this program returns 0, and it occurs with `crazy` and `craza`. And when a try to test with the first string using `bruna` and second string using `bruno` my program returns 1.

```
.data
str1:               .space 32               # para reservar 32 caracteres para as strings
str2:               .space 32
msg1:               .asciiz "Insira a primeira string\n"
msg2:               .asciiz "Insira a segunda string\n"
.text

strcmp:
        li $v0,4
        la $a0,msg1
        syscall

        li $v0,8
        la $a0,str1
        addi $a1,$zero,32

        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0,msg2
        syscall

        li $v0,8
        la $a0,str2
        addi $a1,$zero,32
        syscall   #got string 2

        la $a0,str1  #pass address of str1
        la $a1,str2  #pass address of str2
        jal strAux  #call strcmp

strAux:     add $t0,$zero,$zero
        add $t1,$zero,$a0
        add $t2,$zero,$a1

loop3:
        lb $t3,($t1)  #load a byte from each string
        lb $t4,($t2)
        beqz $t3,checkt2 #str1 end
        beqz $t4,missmatch
        slt $t5,$t3,$t4  #compare two bytes
        bnez $t5,missmatch
        addi $t1,$t1,1  #t1 points to the next byte of str1
        addi $t2,$t2,1
        j loop3

missmatch: 
        addi $v0,$zero,1
        j endfunction
checkt2:
        bnez $t4,missmatch
        add $v0,$zero,$zero

endfunction:    
        move $a0,$v0
        li  $v0,1                       # Opção para imprimir uma string
        syscall
```

Comment: Looks like MARS/SPIM environment code. Both have debugger. Use it to find out more specifically, which part of code doesn't work as expected and why. Although it's very likely you will know the answer at that point, and fix it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slt` is the "Set on Less Than" instruction.  You detect a mismatch only if a character in the first string is *less than* the corresponding character in the second string - but in both of your failing examples, the non-equal character is *greater* in the first string.  I think you want a `subu` instruction there - the result of subtraction will be zero only if the two characters are equal.  Or, replace the two lines there with `bne $t3, $t4, missmatch` - there's no need to put a value in $t5 if you aren't going to use it later.